The quest for the perfect small-scale kegging solution
I'm new! :D
I've been looking for an answer for this conundrum for a long time. Maybe this is the place where all the pieces of the puzzle will come together!
On the surface, the issue is very simple: I'm looking for a reusable kegging solution for a small homebrew setup (5 gallon batches). The constraints: I don't have space for standard size kegs, CO2 tanks, or a separate fridge. All I have is half a shelf of the kitchen fridge.
So, in effect, I'm looking for a solution that involves 5-6 litre kegs (or smaller) that can be primed with sugar for carbonation and take a small CO2 capsule for pouring beer without losing pressure. This setup needs to either fit in a regular fridge or work with a separate device for cooling/dispensing (this is acceptable – I have some spare space on the counter).
There are loads of products that do this, so what is the problem?
It seems products generally fall into three categories.
The first category uses 5-litre metallic mini-kegs like these, which can be tapped with either a 'party star'-style tap like this and put in the fridge, or placed in a separate 'Krups-style' refrigerated system like described in this StackExchange question. The problem: feedback in homebrewing forums is very consistent that these mini-kegs can only be reused a couple of times before the lining starts to fail and a metallic taste is transferred to the beer. So every 23-litre batch would cost me about £15 in mini-kegs, which practically doubles the cost of a recipe.
The second category is very similar, but using high-end 5-litre kegs that can be reused indefinitely. The problem: each of these kegs plus tap system costs upward of £130 (here's an example from Dark Farm). So it'd cost me over £500 to buy 4 of these – the least I need to accommodate a 23-litre batch (and I'd still have to bottle a few). Also, the upright keg + assembly is very awkward for a regular fridge (that's from direct experience – I actually have one of the above).
Which brings us to the third category, which is PET bottles with 'Tap-a-draft'-style systems (this is mentioned in the same StackExchange question mentioned above). The problem: This appears to be very much a US thing – I can't find a reliable seller in the UK, and the few instances that I can find (e.g., here) use 8g CO2 cartdriges that don't seem to be readily available anywhere.
In a perfect world, good-quality kegs would exist in 5L size, making the first category the standout winner since I could get something like a Krups dispenser to keep my beer chilled and no longer have to fight for premium fridge space with my wife. But hey, we don't live in a perfect world, do we?
So, all the above considered... is there something very obvious that I'm missing? Has anyone tried anything different? Any words of wisdom would probably go on to make 2025 the best year of my life!

I have several of these "stainless growlers" that hold a gallon. You can fit regular ball lock adapters to them with this thing and they fit in the fridge. I've pressurized them for longer term storage (couple months) as they come with a screw on cap that has an oring. A co2 attachment and regular picnic tap is what I use for serving. No metallic taste and they clean up pretty easily with a bottle brush. I've had mixed results with all the plastic stuff. Kegland makes PET kegs  but I've not used them. I have some of their red 2 liter bottle adapters which leak and the flow control ball locks don't fit all my posts. It's very odd. Almost like their production tolerances vary widely. Not sure I'd use their plastic kegs.

Nice one thanks!
The stainless growlers look a lot like the Dark Farm ones I linked to. They really are very good, but when you add up the costs of five 5L ones with taps (since each would need their own), costs shoot up very quickly. I could save by going for the 10L ones, but then they won't fit in the fridge :/
Those PET kegs look cool, but I've read through the Kegland website and the one thing they don't say is how exactly I'm supposed to serve beer out of those :D The fittings look made for standard CO2 canisters. Is there a version of this that takes small cartdriges?

Yeah the co2 attachment in the link takes the small BB gun style cartridges.  They have no problem keeping the 128oz (sorry about the freedom units - close to 4 liters)  growler pressurized. I have three of them. Two of them leaked a bit when tested with soapy water so I used a bunch of teflon tape to seal up all the fittings. I guess there's a yellow style tape just for Co2 that you can use. Good luck!
